# Get-ChildItem Where filter not bringing back any results

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will sign my MSI files via powershell.  I have the signing tool sorted, but the issue I am having is getting to my MSI files.

Consider the following folder tree.

```
production
└───deployment
    └───install
        └───validationtool
            │   test.msi
            │
            └───bin
                ├───debug
                │       test.msi
                │
                └───release
                        test.msi
```

The code I am using is

```
$target = "*.msi"
$releaseList = "vt.Setup", "ieh", "vt" 
$requiredFiles = gci $path -recurse -filter $target | ?{ $releaseList -contains ((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)}
```

I am trying to locate MSI files where a folder 3 levels up is one of the folders in the `$releaseList`. Currently now it is not returning the correct folders.

If I just use the line below

```
$requiredFiles = gci $path -recurse -filter $target
```

It brings me back all the MSI files and directories so I know that part is working.

Any and all help very much appreciated. As a bonus if we could omit files with debug in the path that would be helpful.

Comment: What is the bit that doesn't work? What does `Get-WhiteList` do?

Comment: Get-WhiteList returns an array of projects within a solution. 

This does return the results the bit that doesnt work is `| ?{ $releaseList -contains ((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)}`

Comment: You call `Get-MsiFiles` before it is defined. Move the function definition above. If you are running in ISE you might not have noticed this. Same goes for `Get-RequiredMsiFiles`. Definition must  exist before the call

Comment: Have you examined the array `$releaseList` and output of the command `((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)`. This is hard for us to look at since we dont have _any_ sample data to play with and we have to assume that your functions perform the way you say they do.

Comment: Yes, $releaseList does return what it is expected to return when i write it out to the screen via Write-Host.  Given that this works on another function within the same subset of poweshell (ps1) files i have no reason to see why this doesnt work.

Comment: ok... so removing select -Last 1 gives me my array back now... but gives me more than whats in the whitelist..  its giving me all the msi files in the root \ sln folder which is not what i need

Comment: Scratch that last comment... i have it commented out which is why it brought me back everything...  without the commenting out it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see `$releaseList` would have to contain an array of strings. (Have to guess since we can't see the function). Those strings would have to match folder names for your comparison to make sense. Highlighting the following code.

```
((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)
```

It looks like you are returning the grandparent folder of the current file in the pipe. If you the file 'C:\temp\inst - Copy\printer inst.log' for example it would return "temp". If the array `$releaseList` contained an element called "Temp" then this file would satisfy your `Where-Object`

My comments on that are that it really looks like that could be simplified with something like this: `$releaseList -contains [string]($_.Directory.Parent)`

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? Am I wrong about any of this.

**Update after discussion**

After talking in discussion it appear that OP needed to match folders and the logic was correct accept that the folder depth was not correct. The grandparent folder was the one being verfied by the filter. However based on the content of `$releaseList` it was actually a greatgrandparent folder that we need to match. Given how far back you need to go it might be easier to use string manipulation via `.Split()` than the built in cmdlet `Split-Path`

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -filter $target | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname | 
    Where-Object{$releaseList -contains $_.Split('\')[-4]}
```

So if the file you were attempting to match had a path like

> production\deployment\install\validationtool\bin\release\test.msi

we split the path into its parts with `$_.Split('\')` giving

```
production
deployment
install
validationtool   <---- that is the one we are matching against. 
bin
release
test.msi
```

We use `[-4]` to grab the 4th last item which is the folder name "validationtool"

Also, if you were looking to omit debug from the path you could just use another clause like so

```
$releaseList -contains $_.Split('\')[-4] -and $_ -notmatch "debug"
```

And if you wanted to be sure it was just the folder name and not a file with debug in it you could change the match a little.

```
$releaseList -contains $_.Split('\')[-4] -and $_ -notmatch "\\debug\\"
```

Comment: youre right in your assumption, i will try your Directory.Parent solution in a short while and let you know how i get on

Comment: There have been a couple of time that I have mentioned that we are guessing here. Do you have some data samples we can work with. Can you show me the results of `$releaseList.GetType().Fullname`?. Also _no joy on this one_ does not mean much. This comment did not change your code... only make it simpler. Let me know if you can answer my questions. @SimonPrice

Comment: so `$t = gci . -recurse -filter "AssemblyInfo.cs" | ?{ @("SanityChecker") -contains ((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)}` works like this and like this `$t = gci . -recurse -filter "*.cs" | ?{ @("SanityChecker") -contains ((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)}` in one folder sln root but when i go into another sln root and then use the same thing `$t = gci . -recurse -filter "*.msi" | ?{ @("anotherfolder") -contains ((Split-Path $_.Directory).Split('\') | Select -Last 1)}` it fails on me

Comment: Matt, none of what you suggested worked for me sorry

Comment: I have pulled the msi file out of the bin release folder and put it in the project directory and its finding it fine now... so the code i am using is correct

Comment: @SimonPrice Can you show the results from just this `gci . -recurse -filter "*.cs" | Select -Expand Fullname` of the non working folder.

Comment: @SimonPrice I want to see the output. I know its there. I have been blindly troubleshooting this for a while with you now. I can't guess this issue. Can you show me a sample of that output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68354/discussion-between-matt-and-simon-price).

Comment: @SimonPrice that should be updated enough. Edit the question if you need to. I removed the parts that had no  bearing on your actual issue.